# Can't import method Text from androidx.compose.material.Text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[How must I import this method? in the lessons from Google, this problem is solved using this import. but there is no such option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkVt.jpg)

everywhere they write that it is necessary to add  `implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07")` but it doesnt work

Comment: You need add it on gradle menu

Comment: text is part of `androidx.compose.material:material` package

Comment: add it but not work

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `material` or `material3` lib to your project.

Add the dependencies for the artifacts you need in the `build.gradle` file for your app or module:

**groovy**

```
dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.1"
   implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1"
}
```

**kotlin**

```
dependencies {
   implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.1")
   implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1")
}
```

**Note:** select just one of them material or material3.

You can also check last stable version here [Google maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it was necessary to create a project using Empty Compose Activity. And all the imports were added automatically